# Regex for a username?

Tags: c#, regex

In C#, I am trying to validate a username with the following restrictions:

- ​​Uppercase and lowercase English letters (a-z, A-Z)
- Digits 0 to 9
- Acceptable Characters ! # $ % & ' * + - / = ? ^ _ ` { | } ~ \ , . @ ( ) < > [ ]

The username has no restrictions on what character it can start with, all of the above are acceptable. Can you help me come up with this regex, especially the characters I would have to escape because they already mean something in Regex rules?

Comment: You can escape characters using a backslash for the most part

Comment: @General_9 Just so you know, while a regex would work, it's unnecessary. If this isn't for some sort of project that requires you to use regex, you can just have a string of acceptable characters and make sure each character in the username can be found in that string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), you just need to look out for `^`, `-`, `]` and `\`.

The first three must be escaped or placed in unambiguous positions:

- for `^` that's anywhere but the first character inside the class,
- for `-` it's at the start or end of the class,
- for `]` it's at the start of the class (this is possible at least in .NET but not in JavaScript, for example).

The backslash must always be escaped.

So this works:

```
^[]A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~\\,.@()<>[-]*$
```

but I would use

```
^[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~\\,.@()<>[\]-]*$
```

for portability.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/CXLgVmfQG8we5JN7)